# GNU make's SECONDEXPANSION and recursion

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to use GNU make's SECONDEXPANSION (using 3.81, 3.80 and earlier do not support SECONDEXPANSION) as described in the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion), to recurse through a hierarchy of targets by implicit rules. The hierarchy is defined by macros/variables:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION :

top00.subblocks := mid00 mid01
mid00.subblocks := bottom00

wanted : top00.recurse ;
works_but_not_wanted : top00.onelevel ;

%.recurse : %.report $$(addsuffix .recurse,$$($$*.subblocks)) ;
%.onelevel : %.report $$(addsuffix .report,$$($$*.subblocks)) ;

%.report :
    @echo REPORT: $*
```

If I try `make wanted`, it will give:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `top00.recurse', needed by `wanted'.  Stop.
```

If I try `make works_but_not_wanted` it will give:

```
REPORT: top00
REPORT: mid00
REPORT: mid01
```

This is not what I want, since it's not reporting bottom00, will only recurse one level down for obvious reasons. But the target `wanted` fails. It seems GNU make is having trouble with the recursive behavior.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is [documented behavior](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html):

> No single implicit rule can appear more than once in a chain.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So that is even regardless secondary expansion. Do you have any suggestions for the above intended recursion based on the hierarchy definition macros, other than the obvious recursive calls to make?

Comment: Yes, because secondary expansion doesn't create a new pattern rule.  Offhand I don't see why it couldn't work like that but it would be some significant effort to keep track of the previous expansions to ensure there weren't duplicates.